# Artemis is throwing Cannot delete queue on binding - it has consumers

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

We have multiple application servers in a cluster connecting to an instance of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. One of the applications will act as master and the remaining application servers will act as slave nodes.

The master will try to do drop the queue and recreates the queue before producing or consuming the messages as part of the data processing cycle.

Below is the exception stack we are observing in Artemis logs

```
2022-01-03 19:14:55,603 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] Errors occurred during the buffering operation : ActiveMQIllegalStateException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=AMQ229025: Cannot delete queue -1.36.1.level-1.queue on binding -1.36.1.level-1.queue - it has consumers = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.LocalQueueBinding]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.destroyQueue(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2338) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.destroyQueue(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2306) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.destroyQueue(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2297) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.destroyQueue(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2277) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl.destroyQueue(ActiveMQServerImpl.java:2270) [artemis-server-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.removeDestination(OpenWireConnection.java:1062) [artemis-openwire-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection$CommandProcessor.processRemoveDestination(OpenWireConnection.java:1206) [artemis-openwire-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.command.DestinationInfo.visit(DestinationInfo.java:124) [activemq-client-5.16.0.jar:5.16.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.openwire.OpenWireConnection.act(OpenWireConnection.java:323) [artemis-openwire-protocol-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.Actor.doTask(Actor.java:33) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:65) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_292]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]
```

Could you tell me when this would happen and how to avoid it?

Please find below sample code used in dropping the queue:

```java
public void dropQueue() throws JMSException { 
   try { 
      if (connection instanceof ActiveMQConnection && destination instanceof ActiveMQDestination) {
         ((ActiveMQConnection)connection).destroyDestination((ActiveMQDestination)destination);
      } else {
         log.info("Dropping queue : " + queueName + " not supported."); 
      }
   } catch(JMSException e) { 
      throw e; 
   }
}
```

Comment: The Artemis server 2.17.0

Comment: Please find below sample code used in dropping the queue                                           public void dropQueue() throws JMSException  {
  try {
   if (connection instanceof ActiveMQConnection && destination instanceof ActiveMQDestination) {    ((ActiveMQConnection)connection).destroyDestination((ActiveMQDestination)destination);   } else {
    log.info("Dropping queue : " + queueName + " not supported.");
   }
  } catch(JMSException e) {
      throw e;
  }

Comment: We are avioding dropping of the queue . Thanks for the response on this.It is very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broker is logging this WARN message (and not deleting the queue) because the queue you are trying to delete has consumers on it just as the WARN message indicates:

> Cannot delete queue...it has consumers

You can avoid this either by not deleting the queue or removing all the consumers from that queue before deleting it.

In general it's not a good idea for clients to delete queues on the broker since queues are shared resources and may be used by other clients.